# How do I grab essential media information from mpc-hc instance?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to grab media info from my personal fave *Media Player Classic* using a C# app.

Suppose I got the window handle of the MPC-HC instance I'm interested in, but `WM_GETTEXT` only gets me the window title. I'm not satisfied with just that. I want to also grab play state (stopped/paused/playing), current time, total length and file path. I should be able to get all other things from the file, knowing its path.

First thing I thought was using *AutoIt Window Info* app, which gets me just the stuff I want in its *Visible Text* tab, and I'm okay with using it as a tool to get the text, but how am I gonna get *that* text directly to my C# app for parsing?

I'd like to find a solution that doesn't involve interfering with user's activities, like forcibly bringing up front the player's window. I just want to get the current time, play state and full file path into my C# app. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out that by enabling MPC-HC web interface, a nice page appears with all the current player's stats I need at this address: `http://localhost:13579/variables.html` (13579 is the default port, but you may change it in the options). Check *Allow access from localhost only* to protect your secret musical desires ;)

[image]

The HTML on that page is kinda like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MPC-HC WebServer - Variables</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p id="filepatharg">C:\music.mp3</p>
    <p id="filepath">C:\music.mp3</p>
    <p id="filedirarg">C:\</p>
    <p id="filedir">C:\</p>
    <p id="state">1</p>
    <p id="statestring">Paused</p>
    <p id="position">85918</p>
    <p id="positionstring">00:01:25</p>
    <p id="duration">284525</p>
    <p id="durationstring">00:04:44</p>
    <p id="volumelevel">50</p>
    <p id="muted">0</p>
    <p id="playbackrate">1</p>
    <p id="reloadtime">0</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get required information using information retrieved from child windows, look at `EnumChildWindows` function, here is code snippet which demonstrate such behaviour:

```
 class Program
    {
        public delegate bool WindowEnumDelegate(IntPtr hwnd,
                                                 int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hwnd,
                                                  WindowEnumDelegate del,
                                                  int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hwnd,
                                               StringBuilder bld, int size);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var mainWindowHandle = Process.GetProcessesByName("mpc-hc").First().MainWindowHandle;
            var list = new List<string>();
            EnumChildWindows(mainWindowHandle, (hwnd, param) =>
                                               {
                                                   var bld = new StringBuilder(256);
                                                   GetWindowText(hwnd, bld, 256);
                                                   var text = bld.ToString();
                                                   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                                                       list.Add(text);

                                                   return true;
                                               }, 0);

            Console.WriteLine("length={0}", list[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("state={0}", list[1]);
            Console.WriteLine("bitrate={0}", list[5]);
            Console.WriteLine("name={0}", list[7]);

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

You can also explore additional subwindows using [spy++](http://mdb-blog.blogspot.ru/2010/11/microsoft-spy-or-spyxx-for-download.html) like this:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that is fantastic! It's very misleading that the function to get controls is called `EnumChildWindows` though. There is only one window in the player.

Comment: Turns out the index of `list` items varies from file to file. Is there a way to get a name of each item while getting the text? I'd like to use a String dictionary rather than figuring out specific cases.

Comment: Looks like these controls don't have names, but I bet there's a way to find out which is which otherwise than by their list index.

Comment: I checked several files but indexes of metadata information not changes, unfortunately i cannot reproduce indexes changing.